# Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^{k}k}{k^{2}}$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: analysis

So I am trying to figure out if this series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^{k}k}{k^{2}} $$ is absolutely convergent.

I used the triangle inequality to deduce this inequality $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1+(-1)^{k}k}{k^{2}}\right| \le $$ $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|1|+|(-1)^{k}k|}{k^{2}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+k}{k^{2}}$$

Im pretty sure that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+k}{k^{2}}$$ diverges, not sure how to show it though. But I dont think that this will help me out , in showing that the original serie converges absolutely.
Any helps?

Comment: Look for a lower bound. $\dfrac{\lvert 1 + (-1)^kk\rvert}{k^2} \geqslant\,?$

Comment: Im not really sure, the absolute vaue makes me a bit confused.

Comment: You can probably see that $\lvert 1 + (-1)^kk\rvert = \lvert k + (-1)^k\rvert$. What is $\lvert k + (-1)^k\rvert$?

Comment: Actually I cant really see how the first equality holds.. Im feeling a bit dumb now but haha..

Comment: How is $\lvert a\cdot b\rvert$ related to $\lvert a\rvert$ and $\lvert b\rvert$?

Comment: $$|a\cdot{b}|=|a|\cdot{|b|} ?$$

Comment: Yes. and now take $a = (-1)^k$ and $b = 1 + (-1)^kk$.

Comment: Ok,so that should just be equal to $$|b|?$$

Comment: What happens for $k$ even?

Comment: Then we have 1+k in the numerator?

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you still here? I didnt get how the relation $$|ab|=|a|*|b|$$ helps me out in understanding why $$|1+(-1)^{k}k|=|k+(-1)^{k}|?$$

Comment: Because $\lvert (-1)^k\rvert = 1$. Then note that $k + (-1)^k \geqslant 0$ for $k \geqslant 1$, so $\lvert 1 + (-1)^kk\rvert = k + (-1)^k \geqslant k-1$.

Comment: I get that $$|(-1)^{k}| = 1$$ But this still doesnt help me out in seeing why this is true : $$|1+(-1)^{k}k| = |k+(-1)^{k}| $$. Im sorry if im being a bit annoying, but I really cant figure it out..

Comment: $(-1)^k\cdot \bigl(1 + (-1)^kk\bigr) = \,?$

Answer (score 1):

Your series is the termwise sum of these two series:
$$
\sum_{k \geq 0} {1 \over k^2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k \geq 0} {(-1)^{k} k \over k^2}.
$$
The first of these converges by the integral test.  The second converges by the alternating series test: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/convergence-divergence-tests-calc/v/alternating-series-test

Comment: Both series are well-known:  the first series is a Riemann series, the second is the alternating  harmonic series.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the Asker new.  I tried to give the most complete and least prerequisite-heavy answer.

Answer (score 0):

The series does not converge absolutely. As noted in the comments to the question,

$$\begin{align}
|1+(-1)^{k}k|&=|1||1+(-1)^{k}k| \\
&=|(-1)^k||1+(-1)^{k}k| \\
&=|(-1)^{k}+k|\\
&\geq k-1
\end{align}$$

The series $\sum \frac{k-1}{k^2}$ diverges according to the limit comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{k}$. Hence by direct comparison $\sum \frac{|1+(-1)^{k}k|}{k^{2}}$ diverges.